# Redirection to an unformatted, text-only page after trying to edit a deleted answer

Tags: discussion, design, deleted-answers

After clicking on "edit" under an answer, it redirected me to this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44626973/edit

[image: empty deletion page]

Not only is it ugly, but I think that a simple alert box would serve the purpose so much better.

Comment: How did you manage to click "edit" under [an answer that has been deleted and should therefore be invisible to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626973)? It was deleted way back on June 19th, so this isn't just a stale, unrefreshed page you were looking at.

Comment: @CodyGray It appeared when I reviewed answers in a queue.